# Reverse Port Forwarding in iOS over USB

Tags: ios, websocket, usb, mobile-application, portforwarding

I have a web socket server on desktop and client on iPhone device. I would like to communicate with them using USB rather than any network. I have implemented it on android using adb reverse but not able to find any solution for iOS.

I have tried to implement it using usbmuxd and iproxy but they only does port forwarding not the reverse forwarding.I would really appreciate some help on it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will solve your problem, because I did not use the library, but some time ago I've read how Duet Display app is using
https://github.com/rsms/peertalk

Comment: I have already looked into but thats not what I am looking for. PeerTalk uses both its own application on both desktop and device to communicate over USB. I am looking for something like "adb reverse" in android.