# Remote debugging: port forwarding from PC to iOS/iPhone

Tags: ios, usb-debugging

I want to inspect a web app, running on localhost, loaded in phones via USB. I am able to inspect, and remotely control tabs of all connected phones in Chrome at *chrome://inspect/#devices*. However, Chrome's DevTools port forwarding feature only works for Android phones, so I am unable to load the localhost app in the connected iPhone.

Any ideas, how to set port forwarding to the iPhone?

These Q&A didn't work for me, but are related and might help others: [Reverse Port Forwarding in iOS over USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405925/reverse-port-forwarding-in-ios-over-usb), [iPhone testing: port forwarding and localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810329/iphone-testing-port-forwarding-and-localhost). Also searched on Ask Different, but all I got was [Port forwarding on iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/port-forwarding-on-iphone), so I guess it is better to ask here on SO.

I have taken these steps ([Synchronous live debugging of desktop and mobile site versions](https://medium.com/@martin.korvas/synchronous-live-debugging-of-desktop-and-mobile-site-versions-over-usb-using-chrome-vs-code-b27ad40b982e)) to get it up and running, and found this great [guide to enable Inspection/debugging on the iOS](https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/).